# Python: Decorating a class method that is intended to be overwritten when inherited

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator

Let's say I have some base class:

```
class Task:
    def run(self):
        #override this!
```

Now, I want others to subclass Task and override the run() method:

```
class MyTask(Task):
    def run(self):
        #successful override!
```

However, the problem is that there is logic that must take place before and after the run() method of every class that subclasses Task.

It seems like one way I could do this would be to define another method in the base class which then calls the run() method.  However, I wanted to ask, is there a way to achieve this with decorators? What would be the most pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Presumably another process will import the Task subclasses and invoke the run() method. Not sure if that answers your question?

Comment: Why don't you just have them override `run`, but have the API be to call some different method which does the before/after stuff and calls `run` itself?

Comment: Why not just have the `run()` from `Task` do what it has to do and call a function that is overriden in the derived class such as `do_run()`? You are still only asking the derived class to implement one function.

Comment: Yeah, those are all definitely viable options for my use case. I was mostly wondering if there was some decorator magic or if there was a standard way this type of thing is handled.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, letting the subclasses override a hook instead of `run` itself would probably be best:

```
class Task(object):
    def run(self):
        # before 
        self.do_run()
        # after

class MyTask(Task):
    def do_run(self):
        ...

task = MyTask()
task.run()
```

However, this is one way you *could* do it with a class decorator:

```
def decorate_run(cls):
    run = getattr(cls, 'run')
    def new_run(self):
        print('before')
        run(self)
        print('after')
    setattr(cls, 'run', new_run)
    return cls


class Task(object): pass

@decorate_run
class MyTask(Task):
    def run(self):
        pass

task = MyTask()
task.run()

# prints:
# before
# after
```

Another way would be to use a metaclass. The advantage of using a metaclass would be that subclasses wouldn't have to be decorated. `Task` could be made an instance of the metaclass, and then all subclasses of `Task` would inherit the metaclass automatically.

```
class MetaTask(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, clsdict):
        if 'run' in clsdict:
            def new_run(self):
                print('before')
                clsdict['run'](self)
                print('after')
            setattr(cls, 'run', new_run)

class Task(object, metaclass=MetaTask):
    # For Python2: remove metaclass=MetaTask above and uncomment below:
    # __metaclass__ = MetaTask
    pass

class MyTask(Task):
    def run(self):
        #successful override!
        pass

task = MyTask()
task.run()
```

Comment: Thanks for the metaclass magic tip, that's what I was really wondering about.  It looks like I'll probably have others override a hook, but it's really helpful to know that metaclasses are an option.  Thanks!

Comment: I've always seen `__new__` used in metaclasses and not `__init__` - this comes out much cleaner.

Comment: The reason why `__new__` exists in Python is so that immutable types can preserve their immutability while allowing subclassing. (If there were no `__new__` and immutables used `__init__` then you could change the value of immutables by calling things like `math.pi.__init__(3.0)`!) So I believe you should reserve `__new__` only for those situations where you want the instances to be immutable.

Comment: The metaclass example is exactly what I'm looking for but it doesn't seem perform as intended. I'm not seeing is print `before` or `after`. What am I missing?

Comment: @Jørgen: The syntax for declaring a metaclass changed between Python2 and Python3. If you are using Python3, add `metaclass=MetaTask` to the class base declaration. I've edited the post above to show what I mean.

Comment: @unutbu: Thanks for quick response!