# Python: Force decorator inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator

I'm working with quite a large OOP code-base, and I'd like to inject some tracing/logging. The easiest way to do this would be to introduce a decorator around certain methods on some base classes, but unfortunately decorators aren't inherited.

I did try something like the following:

```
def trace(fn):
    def wrapper(instance, *args, **kwargs):
        result = fn(instance, *args, **kwargs)
        # trace logic...
        return result
    return wrapper

class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self.__call__ = trace(self.__call__)  # line added to end of method
```

...and while the `__call__` method **is** wrapped (which I can see from printing the instance information to the console) the `wrapper` function isn't executed as expected.

I also looked briefly at using a metaclass based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18859019/30478), but it instantly breaks other parts of the system that use introspection, so I think that's a no-go.

Is there any other way I can force the application of these decorators around the `__call__` method of classes that inherit from `BaseClass`?

Comment: So you're saying that you want to wrap `__call__` in `BaseClass` and all its children?

Comment: @freakish: yes, sort of. `__call__` in `BaseClass` is overwritten by all the children (and there are many of them) so applying a decorator around `__call__` at the level of `BaseClass` is the easiest way to add the tracing in one place consistently.

Comment: Is this same as what you are trying to solve, decorator on base class inherit to sub-class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782040/python-decorators-that-are-part-of-a-base-class-cannot-be-used-to-decorate-membe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would metaprogramming mess up introspection? Perhaps you are not using it correctly? Try this (assuming Python2.x):

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcl, name, bases, nmspc):
        if "__call__" in nmspc:
            nmspc["__call__"] = trace(nmspc["__call__"])
        return super(MyMeta, mcl).__new__(mcl, name, bases, nmspc)

class BaseClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMeta
```

You can then simply inherit from `BaseClass` and `__call__` will get wrapped automatically.

I'm not sure what kind of introspection would break that. Unless `BaseClass` actually **does not** inherit from `object` but from something that implements its own meta?? But you can deal with that case as well by forcing `MyMeta` to inherit from that parent's meta (instead of `type`).

Comment: This has worked; I think my use of the `__init__` method was causing the introspection to fail, whereas `__new__` "cuts in" at the right point.

Comment: @unpluggd That's weird, I think it can be done with `__init__` as well. I'll dig into it. Although when it comes to metaprogramming I tend to use `__new__` more often.

Comment: I don't think you need to pass `mcl` as an argument in the superclass's `__new__` call; `super` binds that argument already.

Comment: @user2357112 Actually you have to. I'm not sure what happens under the hood but Python throws an exception otherwise. This probably has something to do with the fact that `__new__` fires before the actual instance is created (in this case "instance" means "class").

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that... see things like here: 
[Python method resolution mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923656/python-method-resolution-mystery/5923797#5923797)

Basically. most of special functions are looked up at the *class* level. Monkey-patching it after initialization won't have any effect.

That said, you should be able to do something like this:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    __call__ = trace(object.__call__)
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
```

Now, it's wrapped at the *class* level, so it will work.

edit: That's not really an answer. What you want is something like:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    @decorator
    __call__ = something

class SubClass(BaseClass):
    __call__ = something_else
```

In this case... it doesn't matter what you put for the BaseClass `__call__` method, the SubClass method will override it. It's not about decorators vs. non-decorators, as it's *functions* (well, really, attributes, since there isn't really much difference in python) that get inherited. Decorators *look* separate from the function, but they aren't really - in the above, all that the decorator does is change the definition of `__call__` from `something` to `decorator(something)` (which must still return a callable).

Then, in the subclass, you reassign this function to something completely different.

You could use a class decorator, but those things tend to break introspection as you noticed; they turn a class, into a function that returns a class. Similar problem with factory functions.

Maybe look into the `profile` module? I know there are some lower-level hooks that it uses to track function calls etc. that you might be able to use as well (though don't know much about them).

Comment: Unfortunately my version of `trace` isn't profiling but more tracking data through the system.

Comment: well, my point is that the profiler solves a similar problem - it has to wrap/trace all function calls so it can store start_time/stop_time for each call. you need to do a similar thing, except instead of time them, you'll log them and/or inspect arguments to trace dataflow.